# Fixing bug in removing duplicates from sorted linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, duplicates, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a sorted linked list. I have written the algorithm but still missing a core bug logic that I can't trace.

Consider the list
1->2->3->3->4->4->5

Output should be 1 - > 2 - > 5
The program works fine for a simple case, like 1>2>2>3, but for multiple duplicates like 1>2>2>3>3>5 it outputs 1>3>5
Here is a complete program:

```
struct Node
{
    Node* next;
    int val;
    Node()
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    Node* n1 = new Node();
    n1->val = 1;
    Node* n2 = new Node();
    n2->val = 2;
    n1->next = n2;
    Node* n3 = new Node();
    n3->val = 3;
    n2->next = n3;
    Node* n4 = new Node();
    n4->val = 3;
    n3->next = n4;

    Node* n5 = new Node();
    n5->val = 4;
    n4->next = n5;

    Node* n6 = new Node();
    n6->val = 4;
    n5->next = n6;

    Node* n7 = new Node();
    n7->val = 5;
    n6->next = n7;
    n7->next = nullptr;

    Node* fast = n1->next;
    Node* slow = n1;
    Node* temp = n1;
    Node* prevSlow = nullptr;
    while (slow != nullptr && fast != nullptr)
    {

        if (fast->val == slow->val)
        {
            prevSlow->next = fast->next;
            fast = fast->next;
            slow->next = prevSlow->next;
        }
        else {
            prevSlow = slow;
            slow = slow->next;
            fast = fast->next;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can you point the correct algorithm with two pointers ?

Comment: Some downvoters may require proof of debugging or proof of using a debugger.  For example, indicate which statement is causing your issue.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The program works fine for a simple case, like 1>2>2>3, but for multiple duplicates like 1>2>2>3>3>5 it outputs 1>3>5

Comment: The first pair, 3->3, is handled correctly (apart from the fact that you are leaking nodes): 2 is linked to 4, bypassing the pair. Then `fast` is advanced to the first 4, while `slow` is still pointing to the first `3`; they are now two nodes apart, not one. So they don't even notice the 4->4 pair.

Comment: Also, the program will crash immediately by dereferencing a null pointer is the first two nodes have equal value, as in 1->1->anything.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You touched the correct point. it works perfect for first pair, but second pair doesn't work.. do you know the algorithm to fix it?

Comment: Yes, the shown duplicate removal logic is fundamentally flawed. It should be reimplemented from scratch, and be half the size of the shown code. It should not require four separate pointers, that serve unclear purposes. This should require just one pointer for the loop and a second, temporary, pointer used only when removing a duplicate entry. I expect plenty of examples of this sort in every introductory C++ textbook's chapter on linked lists.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh You need to learn to use a debugger. Run the program step by step and write what you observe on paper. For such small data, it should take less time to find the problem by yourself that writing the question. Also your code have **memory leaks** as you don't delete nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this constructor

```
Node()
{

}
```

does not make a sense. Remove it.

The statement

```
prevSlow->next = fast->next;
```

in this if statement

```
if (fast->val == slow->val)
{
    prevSlow->next = fast->next;
    fast = fast->next;
    slow->next = prevSlow->next;
}
```

in general can invoke undefined behavior because initially the pointer `prevSlow` is set to `nullptr`

```
Node* prevSlow = nullptr;
```

Pay attention to that the node n1 is the head node of the list. It can be changed in the process of removing duplicates. Also you need to free memory of removed nodes.

The algorithm can be implemented the following way

```
auto is_duplicate = [] ( const Node *node )
{
    return node->next != nullptr && node->val == node->next->val;
};

for ( Node **current = &n1; *current != nullptr; )
{
    if ( is_duplicate( *current ) )
    {
        do
        {
            Node *tmp = *current;
            *current = ( *current )->next;
            delete tmp;
        } while ( is_duplicate( *current ) );

        Node *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, is it not possible with two pointers ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh I think it will be more complicated.